# Java Wont Work with Visual Studio Code anymore

Tags: java, spring-boot

With literally **zero** external input from me, Java just completely stopped working for VSC. When I open my projects with NetBeans everything works fine. 
I tired to create a fresh new project with spring boot to see if that would run. It did not.
I have a plugin which puts a 'run' button above the main method. When I press it it just inputs this in console and does nothing else:

> c:\Users\aUSER\Desktop\prj\demo>cd c:\Users\aUSER\Desktop\prj\demo && C:\Users\aUSER.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.24.0\scripts\launcher.bat "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 @C:\Users\aUSER\AppData\Local\Temp\cp_8z7bhlty5upwdf6m7p4sx4len.argfile com.example.demo.DemoApplication

It was literally working fine yesterday...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you either

1. reinstall visual studio and keep your solutions saved on a usb drive or
2. make sure you have installed the right plugins on your visual studio as those can sometimes get broken (personal experience)

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Gotta love it when random things break for no reason. I reinstalled **EVERYTHING**. Didn't work. I removed everything, restarted, reinstalled it all for the second time; this time. It worked.... because of course it did.